# QML: Dynamic view re-ordering in original model

Tags: qt, listview, drag-and-drop, qml, qt5

Implemented QML Dynamic View Ordering by Dragging View Items using this Qt tutorial: [QML Dynamic View Ordering Tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-dynamicview-tutorial.html). Original underlying model is `QAbstractListModel` descendant in our case. Model stores data in a `QList<QObject*> objectList;` field type. Works fine, however item ordering changed in proxy `DelegateModel` only.

How to change items order automatically in original underlying model as well for other C++ and QML consumers where order matters? Or I could we otherway access some resulted (sorted) List Model model from C++ somehow?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [QML Dynamic View Ordering Tutorial 3](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-tutorials-dynamicview-dynamicview3-example.html) example I've replaced `visualModel.items.move()` call with my `ObjectListModel::move()` method like this:

**ObjectListModel : public QAbstractListModel**:

```
void ObjectListModel::move(int from, int to)
{
    if(0 <= from && from < count() && 0 <= to && to < count() && from != to) {
        if(from == to - 1) // Allow item moving to the bottom
            to = from++;

        beginMoveRows(QModelIndex(), from, from, QModelIndex(), to);
        objectList.move(from, to);
        endMoveRows();
    }
}
```

**Delegate component**:

```
DropArea {
    anchors { fill: parent; }

    onEntered: {
        let from = drag.source.DelegateModel.itemsIndex
        let to = mouseArea.DelegateModel.itemsIndex
        objectListModel.move(from, to)
    }
}
```

And above works perfectly for the `ListView` and `ObjectListModel` itself - I have checked: items (and therefore objects) are moved correctly, indexes are correct, C++ consumers works just fine and take new order into account correctly, etc.

---

However another consumer like `MapItemView` fails to use the model after `beginMoveRows`/`endMoveRows` calls: moved item disappeared on the map and other manipulations with an item crashes the app.

```
 Map {
     ...
     MapItemView {
         model: objectListModel

         delegate: SomeItemIndicator {
         }
     }
 }
```

Reported [QTBUG-81076](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-81076) bug, which is confirmed.

**Workaround:**

Found workaround for now: created 2nd duplicate model which content will be replaced completely on every change in the 1st model on every add/delete/moving(reordering). Above works since `beginResetModel`/`endResetModel` works correctly for `MapItemView`. So `MapItemView` now utilizes only the 2nd model. So on every 1st model change this method is called for the 2nd model:

```
QObjectList ObjectListModel::swapObjectList(const QObjectList& newlist)
{
    QObjectList oldlist(_objectList);
    beginResetModel();
    _objectList = newlist;
    endResetModel();
    return oldlist;
}
```